# How to get Lantronix XPort IP address programmatically

Tags: java, ip

Typically we use Lantronix [DeviceInstaller](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/utilities-tools/device-installer.html) to get the IP address of an [XPort](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/xport.html) Embedded Ethernet Device Server. I need to add this feature to a Java GUI since Lantronix [DeviceInstaller](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/utilities-tools/device-installer.html) is strictly a Windows application and my application needs to run on various flavors of Windows and Linux. What is the best way to get the IP address of a Lantronix [XPort](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/xport.html) Embedded Ethernet Device Server without using Lantronix [DeviceInstaller](http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/utilities-tools/device-installer.html)?

Comment: +1 do balance it, please, when you vote negative, add a comment to explain why !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Michael Lyon at Lantronix Technical Support:

> The discovery process involves sending hex 00 00 00 F8 to UDP 30718.
>   If you broadcast this, all Lantronix CobOS (including XPort) will send
>   a response that starts with hex 00 00 00 F9. The response from each
>   device is exactly 120 bytes and will always start with the hex 00 00
>   00 F9 when the query starts with hex 00 00 00 F8. The four hex values
>   immediately after the F9 are the responding unit's IP address in hex.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this with Linux commands?

Comment: @Davy. You may want to contact Lantronix Technical Support directly.